# How can the application detect the user and/or the device have never installed the application before

Tags: android, security

## Scenario

The user get only the first time free credits in the app. After that we want to do fraud prevention. We need to check if the user and/or the device have not installed the application before.

We can accept the risk of a factory reset or rooted devices

## What I tried already

- Listen to Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH. After reading I understand that this event is only send to the Play store and can't be used in any other app.
- Check the application package info for the field "firstInstallTime", this is reset when the user removed the application and do a install.
- Android Backup Service, but the user can stop the backup and reset data, so this is at no use.
- [App licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html) looks like a promise solution to detect if the user have already installed the app. But with limitations the following is described: "You can implement licensing controls for a free app, but only if you're using the service to provide APK expansion files." Do we need to make a small APK expension file, just to verify the license?"
- make a fingerprint of the mac address, imei, android id and some other stuff. But would this make the scans of Google play violating? I don't use it for advertising, but i'm afraid they think we violate the google play policy.

## how you can help me

Can you help me to choose a good direction to solve this issue and maybe give some better methods to do this verification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory reset, second-hand phones and users with multiple devices will be your main problems.
The only way to uniquely identify a user is an authentication through login/password or OpenId account.

Comment: updated the question, we can accept some fraud prevention trough factory reset or rooted devices. login/password trough openID is to much hassle for our users.

Comment: You said the User And/Or Device, surely this means they are already logging in to something, if that is the case validate it through this. Otherwise you will probably have to create a folder in the external memory (if you end the name with a '.' it will be classed as 'hidden') in your application check it exists. It is not foolproof, but if you are not willing to do web auth  people will find ways around it.

Comment: @Extranion The best guide for this common problem is here: http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: @ChrisHandy the problem is that users can sign up without a account to lower the effort they need to do. We thought about it to put a file on the sd card but if you have a clean device the fraudsters detect that really easy.

Comment: @Gorcyn Good article thanks :) But I also mentioned the ANDROID_ID, I'm worried that google wil punish our app, by using it. They have add the advertiser id's for advertisement and we had recently a warning in the google play console to remove the library that use this type of fingerprinting.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there if you are managing user information at the your server than what you can do is take the IMEI number of the device and send it to your server. It will record the information of the user. Now if he/she uninstall and install app again your app will again send IMEI number at server now you can check the IMEI already present or not, If present then user have already installed your application, more over you can manage same thing from the login ID, but that can be faked by the user. More over it will not violate any thing. User can see while installing in the permissions that your app will get the system information.

Comment: You can add the another information email id etc , there is only one thing you can do for is sharedPreference but that will also get removed when user will uninstall the application.

Comment: else there is nothing which can let you know that user already exit. Your application should manage every user separately. just like facebook. if some one using fake information then still he/she have to pay.